# get_option function return Undefined index

Tags: codeigniter

im new codeigniter student . i make this function for get option value in database ( in function_helper.php ) in helper folder . but i cant get any result

```
function get_option($name, $default = '') {

    $CI = &get_instance();

    $query =  $CI->db->get_where('setting',array('s_name'=>$name),1);

    $result = $query->result();

    return $result['s_value'];
}
```

i tested `result_array()` and `row_array()` instead `result()` but still return this error :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: s_value

Filename: helpers/functions_helper.php

Line Number: 27
```

**Update 1** : `print_r($result)` return `Array( )`

**Update 2** : i use this simple code in main controller but nothing return :

```
$query = $this->db->get('setting');

        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
            echo $row->s_name;
            }
```

**Update 3** : Changing dbdriver from pdo to mysql update 2 code work . but still return same error for main problem and reyurn : `Message: Trying to get property of non-object`

**Update 4** : after update 3 `print_r($result);` return :

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 4 [s_name] => test [s_value] => bbbbbbbbbbbbb ) )
```

but `return $result->s_value;` still return `Message: Trying to get property of non-object`

**Update 5 : i find answer i publish in new answer**

Comment: @PravinS return this error : Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Please use print_r($result) and see the return data structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution :

1 : Change DBdriver from pdo to mysqli .

2 : this function :

```
function get_option($name, $default = '') {

    $CI = &get_instance();

    $query =  $CI->db->get_where('setting',array('s_name'=>$name),1);    
    $result = $query->row_array();

    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
        return $result['s_value'];
    }
    return $default; //if now records found return something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

may be your query is not returning any rows, its always good to check number of rows before actually trying to access it, as:

```
function get_option($name, $default = '') {

    $CI = &get_instance();

    $query =  $CI->db->get_where('setting',array('s_name'=>$name),1);    
    $result = $query->result();

    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
        return $result->s_value;
    }
    return ""; //if now records found return something
}
```

Comment: i use this function but still return : Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @user3243573 what does echo $query->num_rows(); show..?

Comment: return 1 number . seems when return value error occurs

Comment: @user3243573 do you have the field named 's_value' in your setting table..?

Comment: setting table contain : id,s_name,s_value and id is key in number A_I and both of s_name and s_value are text field .

Comment: what does var_dump($result); show..? does it show s_value in it..?

Comment: var_dump($result) return array(0) { }